# Proving maximum of independent unit exponentials behaves like $\log n$

Tags: probability-theory, almost-everywhere

I want to prove $P(\lim_n{\max_1^n X_i \over \log n}=1)=1$ where $X_i$ are i.i.d Exp$(1)$. I was able to to show that

$$\left\{\lim_n{\max_1^n X_i \over \log n}=1\right\}=
\left(\lim\inf\left\{{\max_1^n X_i \over \log n}>1-\epsilon\right\}\right) \bigcap \left(\lim\inf\left\{{\max_1^n X_i \over \log n}<1+\epsilon\right\}\right)$$

$$=\lim\inf C_n\cap\lim\inf D_n\,\,\,\text{ (say)}$$

I was also able to show that $P({\lim\sup X_n \over \log n}=1)=1$ and 
$$\left\{{\lim\sup X_n \over \log n}=1\right\} = 
\left(\lim\sup\left\{{X_n \over \log n}>1-\epsilon\right\}\right) \bigcap \left(\lim\inf\left\{{X_n \over \log n}<1+\epsilon\right\}\right)$$
$$=\lim\sup A_n\cap\lim\inf B_n\,\,\,\text{ (say)}$$

I was further able to show $A_n\subset C_n\subset\cup_1^nA_i$ and $D_n\subset B_n$

How can I conclude the result I want?

PS: This question has been posted before but the answer use "Gumbel Distribution", I am looking for a more Set Theoretic / Borel Cantelli lemma type answer if possible

Here the question asked: [Almost sure convergence of maximum of sequence of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692623/almost-sure-convergence-of-maximum-of-sequence-of-random-variables)